# Controlling resource usage in Julia lang

Tags: julia, daemon

I want to build a software that will run every once in a while, automatically, to sort significant number of files sitting in my disk in Julia.

I tried to do it with the following code, but eats up my resources.

```
while true
// if it's 6 O'clock in the morning, runs function for batch processing
end
```

How can I limit the resource usage?

Comment: adding a `sleep(0.1)` under `while true` is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Timer`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Timer-Tuple%7BFunction,Real%7D) events instead of using a loop. All you need to do is to define a callback function that takes a `Timer` argument and does the job you want.

```
julia> begin
         myfun(timer) = println("Sort Files")
         t = Timer(myfun, 2, interval = 0.2) # after 2 seconds the task will run for each 0.2 seconds interval
         wait(t) # the timer events will trigger forever if you want to stop the events you should call close(t) somewhere in the future
       end
```

You can stop the timer in your function based on a condition using `close(timer)`, or just later on by calling `close(t)` somewhere else that has access to `t`.

With `Timer`s, you can still keep on using your julia instance for other purposes.

Comment: Yours is straight forward.

Comment: For production systems I would recommend tools built-in within the operating system such as `crontab` on Linux. This is usually more robust in the long run.